# How to make a checkbox change its state when clicked?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a checkbox in WinAPI using the following code:

```
HWND checkbox = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "BUTTON", "Click Me!", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, 10, 10, 60, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

I expected the checkbox to change its state automatically when clicked, however it did not!

I did not find any example on MSDN, so how can I make the checkbox change its state when clicked? should I handle the `WM_COMMAND` message and see what state it is in, and then change its state to the opposite one?

Comment: Change it's state to what? Disabled?

Comment: @Andreas DM to checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `BS_AUTOCHECKBOX` style instead of `BS_CHECKBOX`.

[Button Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx)

> BS_AUTOCHECKBOX
>  
>   Creates a button that is the same as a check box, **except that the check state automatically toggles between checked and cleared each time the user selects the check box.**

[Button States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775945.aspx)

> Elements of a Button State
>
> A button's state can be characterized by its focus state, push state, and check state.
>
> ...
>
> Check State
>   ...
>   The system automatically changes the check state of an **automatic button**, but the application must change the check state of a **non-automatic button**.
>
> Changes to a Button State
>
> When the user selects a button, it is generally necessary to change one or more of the button's state elements. **The system automatically changes ... the check state for all automatic buttons. The application must make all other state changes**, taking into account the button's type, style, and current state.